# how can install this file and remove this error

Tags: software-installation

```
mhn@mhn-Inspiron-560s:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install openmpi-3.0.1rc2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openmpi-3.0.1rc2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'openmpi-3.0.1rc2'
```

Comment: look for the package in the repo like `apt-cache search openmpi` then pick up the proper one by definition. In your case it might be `sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin`

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you might be missing the apt ppa for wherever that package is coming from. Doing a quick google search i couldn't find it.

Download the package from this url:
`http://beopen.bplaced.net/2018/01/open-mpi-3-0-1rc2/`

unpacking it (it's a gzip) and following the instructions in the included INSTALL file.

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but it won't let me since I am fairly new to this community. Have you tried the following [instructions](http://lsi.ugr.es/jmantas/pdp/ayuda/datos/instalaciones/Install_OpenMPI_en.pdf)?

The command you would be looking for is:

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin openmpi-common openssh-client openssh-server libopenmpi1.3 libopenmpi-dbg libopenmpi-dev
```

Though this will install the current version which is v3.0. It seems you are trying to install a prerelease which might not be available through apt-get as suggested by @tranfuria.

Comment: No need to comment: that's and answer and you have your first upvote!  **:-)**